# plugin:vite:import-analysis - Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. - Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I've updated my project from Vite 2.x to Vite 3.0.2 and suddenly i got this error:

> [plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import
> analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are
> using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
>
> /Volumes/Disk/Web/wce-system/src/i18n.js:51:20

[image: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax.]

There's nothing wrong in i18n.js file as it was working fine with Vite 2.x but im putting codes in here just in case you need:

```
import { nextTick } from "vue"
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n"
import axios from "axios"
import tr from "@/locales/tr.json"
import en from "@/locales/en.json"

export const SUPPORT_LOCALES = ["tr", "en"]

export function setupI18n(options = { locale: "tr" }) {
const i18n = createI18n(options)
setI18nLanguage(i18n, options.locale)
  return i18n
}

export function setI18nLanguage(i18n, locale, url) {
  if (i18n.mode === "legacy") {
  i18n.global.locale = locale
} else {
  i18n.global.locale.value = locale
}       
axios.defaults.headers.common["Accept-Language"] = locale
document.querySelector("html").setAttribute("lang", locale)
}

export async function loadLocaleMessages(i18n, locale) {
 const messages = await import(
/* webpackChunkName: "locale-[request]" */ `./locales/${locale}.json`
)

i18n.global.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages.default)
 return nextTick()
}

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: "tr",
  fallbackLocale: "tr",
  globalInjection: true,
  messages: {
    tr,
    en,
  },
})

export default i18n
```

Comment: I got this error because I moved my index.html file into a subfolder. It HAS to be in the root, even though the documentation says you can build a subdirectory. I have found that to be false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So i figured it out. This line:

```
const messages = await import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "locale-[request]" */ `./locales/${locale}.json`
)
```

should have been:

```
 const messages = await import(`./locales/${locale}.json`)
```

I cant explain why it is so but im leaving links below about issue.

[Vite dynamic imports](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import)

[This](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations) may help for further investigation

Answer (score 3):

I had same error and fixed like this:

Change file format from .js to .jsx

Answer (score 1):

I've got this particular error after migrate from vue CLI to vite.

"Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files."

I googled and I found a lot of remarks and some solutions but none are available in my case.
And then after a long times , I look in my IDE and it dispaly a topic " remove the uncessary parentheses" and then after removing the uncessary parenthesis all was fine.

In my code I've write

```
export default ({ .. some code });
```

after removing the () the error disappear.

```
export default { .. some code };
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

During migration to Vue3, my issue was not including the Vite `@vite-js/plugin-vue` plugin in vite.config.js. This is needed for Vite to support Vue Single-File Components (SFCs).

```
// vite.config.js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default {
  plugins: [
     vue()
  ],
}
```

[@vitejs/plugin-vue repo](https://@vite-js/plugin-vue)

Comment: Had the same, my `vite.config.js` was in another location. I found out using `vite build --debug`, it says something like "no configuration".

Answer (score 1):

I found this misleading error because of a simple syntax error in a JavaScript file part of a TypeScript React app:

```
import { Foo } from 'baz';

export class MyClass{
    static myFunc() {
        return ...;
    //} <- missing curly brace here
}
```

Adding the missing brace fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting this exact same error with SvelteKit (+server.page for example), the issue can be a syntax problem elsewhere in the code - so do as above and strip the code back, building it up until you can identify it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So the problem is that there is a problem somewhere? Not sure how this is helpful

Comment: Is this 2023? If your framework requires you to do this in order to spot bugs then there is an issue with the framework design.

Answer (score 0):

make sure all following files are in your project root.

```
svelte.config.js
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.node.json
vite.config.ts
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install vue with **npm install**
Then run your build using **npm run build**

Answer (score -1):

The thing is Vite is strict the way you name your files and folders.
make sure you start with capital letter when naming your files and folders, and use jsx file type in naming your files.

Example:

Components/Home/Home.jsx