# Vue3 and Vite failed load JSON with Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, vuejs3, vite

I'm migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3. Doing test app first.

I'm having trouble importing a JSON file.

[image: This error I'm getting]

The file exists. Tried all these variants:

```
import { sites } from "./data/sites.json";
import sites from "./data/sites.json";
import sites from "../data/sites.json";
import sites from "@/data/sites.json";
```

https://www.koderhq.com/tutorial/vue/local-json/ and https://codesandbox.io/s/z2mpz6zq23?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

[Sandbox Link - dev - This doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq49w.png)

Thanks @Tolbxela I tried that:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/adavie1/vite-vue3-test/dev?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FGoodTable.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A23%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A11%2C%22startColumn%22%3A23%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A11%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9m0zoma000flqdd0e60a416%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D) doesn't run, so I recreated it in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qisvlu?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FGoodTable.vue).

Your directory layout looks like this:

```
src
├── components
│   └── GoodTable.vue
├── data
│   └── sites.json
```

Notice `import rows from './data/sites.json'` in [`src/components/GoodTable.vue`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qisvlu?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FGoodTable.vue%3AL24-L24). `./data/sites.json` is a relative path, so the lookup is relative to the importing file's directory, which is `src/components`. `src/components/data/sites.json` does not exist, so Vite displays an error.

The JSON file is actually one parent level up in `src/data/sites.json`, so you need to update the import path to:

```js
import rows from '../data/sites.json'
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9zxmym?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FGoodTable.vue%3AL22)

Answer (score 0):

Your app in the sandbox is working well. Check the screenshot.

I would guess the problem is with your browser.
Be sure it supports the `import` statement ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)).

[image: it works]

**UPDATE**:

I've checked your screenshot. You have an import problem in the Vite (plugin:vite:import-analysis)

Check these links to solve:

[Vite - Dynamic Import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import)

[StackOverflow - plugin:vite:import-analysis - Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. - Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73033899/pluginviteimport-analysis-failed-to-parse-source-for-import-analysis-because)

Comment: Links aren't mine.

Comment: Migrated to JavaScript same problem.

Comment: The problem is Vite- Did test project with vue-cli (which uses Webpack) works fine.

Comment: Done Vite Test project: If I import JSON App.vue it works:  `import data from './data/sites.json'`. If I try load anywhere else, for example HeeloWorld.vue problem as above.

Comment: @Anthony, I have no experience with Vite unfortunately. So, it hard to help. The Docs could help you. Take a look at the glob import: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import. It looks like the way you should investigate.

Comment: Thanks for link. I tried that also. `const sites = await import(...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160048/vue3-and-vite-json-file-loads-app-ok-not-any-other-compoennt